# How to display level lines in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to display level lines (└──) like on the screenshot.
But I looked all settings and didn't find such option.

[image: IntelliJ]

Comment: I assume that the screenshot is from a real Idea running instance? What version?

Comment: @Magnilex [youtube](https://youtu.be/PuEZ7OFyDis?t=255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you cannot configure intellij to show those lines.

The version shown in screenshot is old version of intellij (14 and lower).